# Sprite Kit: FPS getting lower every time I restart my game (simulator)

Tags: sprite-kit, ios-simulator

I'm losing FPS every time I restart my game (pressing the restart button in my game).
the odd thing about it It's not happen on real device.
Is it's supposed to be like that on simulator ?

Comment: The simulator is slow to begin with. There could be countless problems with your code though, like not cleaning up previous nodes or creating one set too many nodes every time you restart. Without narrowing down the problem to a specific piece of code and posting that here we can't help.

Comment: I'm Having the same nodes (around 15-20) the whole game, I guess it's the simulator issue. thnx for the comment tho' .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  There is a known issue with the simulator.  The simulator is slow and there is also an issue rendering the stroke of shapeNodes.  If it works on a device, it will work for your customers!